# Not able to sort using Smart Table in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I am using smart table but I am not able to sort the table, the following is my code

```
<div ng-app="app">
        <div ng-controller="app-controller">
            <table st-table="EmployeeDetails" class="table table-striped table-hover" st-safe-src="EmployeeData">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th st-sort="EmployeeName">Employee Name</th>                       
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="employee in EmployeeData">
                        <td class="col-xs-2">
                            <small>{{employee.EmployeeName}}</small>                           
                        </td>                        
                    </tr>                  
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('app', []);
        app.controller('app-controller', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope,$http) {
            $http.get('/Data/EmployeeDetails.json').success(function (data) {              
                $scope.EmployeeData = data;
            }).error(function () {
                alert('error');
            });
        }]);       
    </script>
```

can anyone let me know what exactly is wrong, i have referenced both angular.js and smart-table.js

```
<script src="../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/smart-table.js"></script>
```

Comment: is there anyone know the answer, please post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use 'EmployeeDetails' at ng-repeat
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/redpeaks/uqvbffw7/)

OK

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in EmployeeDetails">
```

NG

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in EmployeeData">
```

Thanks